# Rosserial error: "Buffer overrun when attempting to parse setup message."

Tags: ros, rosserial, buffer, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating an application to control the Baxter robot with the Oculus Rift. Everything worked fine but after simply copying the program to another computer and running it from there, I am getting the error "Buffer overrun when attempting to parse setup message" at initialisation.

I am using two computers, obtaining and publishing data (using Rosserial Windows) on a Windows PC and creating ROS subscribers + processing the data on an Ubuntu PC. I migrated the code from my Windows laptop onto a Windows desktop, but haven't changed it otherwise. The error occurs immediately as the Windows node attempts to connect.

I am not sure what triggered the error, since I haven't changed my code. Apparently, it is caused by the StreamOverrun exception. More specifically, Rosserial's Session.h shows when the exception is triggered - I am also getting that ROS_ERRROR_ONCE message, which suggests topic_id < 100. I don't understand how that could be the case:

```
try {
          callbacks_[topic_id](stream);
        } catch(ros::serialization::StreamOverrunException e) {
          if (topic_id < 100) {
            ROS_ERROR("Buffer overrun when attempting to parse setup message.");
            ROS_ERROR_ONCE("Is this firmware from a pre-Groovy rosserial?");
          } else {
            ROS_WARN("Buffer overrun when attempting to parse user message.");
          }
        }
```

For reference, my code can be found on [my github](https://github.com/retepvan/Oculus-Baxter).

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269771/rosserial-error:-%22buffer-overrun-when-attempting-to-parse-setup-message.%22/) by [retepvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30758/retepvan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I discovered what the issue was. Optimisation set in the Release Configuration in Visual Studio of my Rosserial Windows application was causing problems. The solution was to disable optimisation.

---

Originally posted by [retepvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30758/retepvan/) with karma: 16 on 2017-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-03**:
If changing the optimalisation levels really works-around / resolves this, then I think that would be something to report at [rosserial/issues](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues), as it would seem to point to a serious issue.

**Comment by [retepvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30758/retepvan/) on 2017-09-03**:
Cheers, I will do that.